# JavaScriptSerializer not working with enum when specify assign an index value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, javascriptserializer

A class that contains an enum property and serializing the object using JavaScriptSerializer. 
When i serialize the JSON i am getting index value rather the text.
As an example:

```
    public enum LocationType
    {
        [Description("Description 1") ,EnumMember(Value = "EST")]
        EST = 1,
        [Description("Description 2"), EnumMember(Value = "INTNS")]
        INTNS = 2,
        [Description("Description 3"), EnumMember(Value = "INTS")]
        INTS = 3
    }
public class Details
    {
        public LocationType? LocationType { get; set; }
    }

List<Details> obj = new List<Details>();
            obj.Add(new Details() { LocationType = LocationType.INTNS });
            obj.Add(new Details() { LocationType = LocationType.INTS });
            obj.Add(new Details() {  LocationType = LocationType.EST });
            obj.Add(new Details() { LocationType = LocationType.INTS });
            obj.Add(new Details() {  LocationType = LocationType.EST });
            obj.Add(new Details() {  LocationType = LocationType.EST });
            obj.Add(new Details() {  LocationType = LocationType.INTS });
            obj.Add(new Details() {  LocationType = LocationType.EST });

        return obj;
```

Actual json result:

```
{ "LocationType ": 2 }
```

Expected json result:

```
{ "LocationType ": "INTNS" }
```

Comment: I can't use LocationType.INTNS.Value for Enum. It will return INTNS when using LocationType.INTNS

Comment: Use Json.Net it's much better. Even MS themselves have stopped using the JavaScriptSerialzer these days in preference to Json.Net

Comment: When i using newtonsoft it will working fine as i am expected but i need to achive this case in javascriptserializer

Answer (score 0):

Okay i just tested, and as suspected you are assigning the enum a value twice. 
if you want to assign it to "string" value instead of and int. You dont need to set it to an int as shown in the article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts

So if you do it like this it will work:

```
public enum LocationType
{
    [Description("Description 1") ,EnumMember(Value = "EST")]
    EST,
    [Description("Description 2"), EnumMember(Value = "INTNS")]
    INTNS,
    [Description("Description 3"), EnumMember(Value = "INTS")]
    INTS
}
```

You might need to call a ToString() on the enum when using the value:

```
LocationType.INTNS.ToString();
```

Comment: This is not a proper solution we need that corresponding index

Comment: When i using newtonsoft it will working fine as i am expected but i need to achive this case in javascriptserializer